# combine facet_grid and boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I want to make a facet-grid combined with boxplots. The facets should be the variable `Experiment` The boxplot should show value against FC for every variable.The variable and Experiment has multiple levels. 
Do I need to use gridExtra?
I tried this, which is obviously wrong:

```
df.m

    FC          Experiment     variable value
1  -1.36811678 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1    no
2  -0.59630399 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1   yes
3  -0.09747337 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1    no
4   1.71652821 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1   yes
5  -1.13473546 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1    no
6  -0.44012950 Ago2 Knockout     Pos1   yes


ggplot(df.m,aes(value,FC,fill=as.factor(value))) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch=T) + facet_grid(~Experiment)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simulate some data if there's too much to post (and, knowing the levels of the various factors would also be helpful), but you were on the right track for the plot, you just needed to add an interaction for `variable` and `value`. I did the following with `facet_wrap` but you could just as easily use `facet_grid`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# create reproducible simulated data
set.seed(1492)
dat <- data.frame(FC=runif(100, min=-2, max=2),
                  Experiment=rep(c("Ago1", "Ago2", "Ago3", "Ago4"), 25),
                  variable=rep(c("Pos1", "Pos2", "Pos3", "Pos4", "Pos5"), 20),
                  value=sample(c("yes", "no"), 100, replace=TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=interaction(variable, value), y=FC))
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=value))
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Experiment)
gg <- gg + labs(x="")
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill="black"))
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text=element_text(color="white", face="bold"))
gg
```

You could have created another column with the combined `variable` and `value` factor instead of using `interaction` explicitly in the `ggplot` call, which would also make it easier to change/have more control the x-axis labeling.

[image]